# How to click a button using "Control Click" keyword?

Tags: autoit, robotframework

What is the syntax of AutoIt library's "Control Click" keyword in Robot Framework? Step 1, 2 and 3 are working:

1. Start app using batch file.
2. Click "Next >" button using coordinates with "Mouse Click".
3. Click a text box and input some text.
4. Click "Next >" button.

Using "Control Click" I am getting :

> com_error: (-2147352561, 'Parameter not optional.', None, None)

Robot file:

```
***Settings***

Library     AutoItLibrary
Library     Collections
Library     String

*** Variables ***

${Run_batchfile}        C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\software_install.bat
${Title}                Setup - test software

***Test Cases***

testcase1
    Run                 ${Run_batchfile}
    Wait For Active Window      ${Title}        TimeOut=140
    Mouse Click         strButton=LEFT, nX=887, nY=523, nClicks=2, nSpeed=1000
    Mouse Click         strButton=LEFT, nX=456, nY=225, nClicks=1, nSpeed=-1
    Wait For Active Window      ${Title}
    Send                strSendText=, c:\\test_te

    Control Click       strTitle=${Title}, strText=${Title}, strControl=1, strButton=Next >, nNumClicks=2, nX=888, nY=524
```

Run time logs:

> C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt>pybot auto.robot
> ============================================================================== Auto
> ============================================================================== testcase1
> . C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt>echo off testcase1
> | FAIL | com_error: (-2147352561, 'Parameter not optional.', None,
> None)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Auto
> | FAIL | 1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed 1 test total, 0 passed, 1
> failed
> ============================================================================== Output:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt\output.xml Log:
> C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt\log.html Report:
> C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt\report.html
>
> C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW with AutoIt>

Comment: May be you wanted to check this link from robotframework-user list group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/robotframework-users/press$20control$20key/robotframework-users/mHRq6o-T7a4/GiYn8V87CwAJ  (may be you need to login into gmail account if it is not working for you to view this topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
Control Click  ${title}  ${EMPTY}  [CLASS:Button;TEXT:Next >]
```

It seems that the parameter names are documentation only.

Without the [controlID](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/controls.htm) (third parameter) youre getting the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

The way you used control click is wrong I think. You should have at least separated the arguments with at least two (2) spaces, not with ", ". So, this would be:

`Control Click    strTitle=${Title}    strText=${Title}    strControl=1    strButton=Next >    nNumClicks=2    nX=888    nY=524`

In my code, I used four (4) spaces, which what Robot Framework recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have tried many many things before I was able to get it work using the back slash "\" as separator without any attributes or titles just proving the button name (ClassnameNN value) from "AutoIt V3 Window info":

```
 Control Click       \    \   Button1
```

Answer (score -1):

I think just Remove the Arguments name from your code ie. strButton=,strTitle=,nX=, nY=,nClicks= In RF only need to put like this...

```
testcase1
Run                 ${Run_batchfile}
Wait For Active Window      ${Title}        TimeOut=140 
Mouse Click    LEFT    887    523    2    1000
```